# can't reach unordered list if it's created in the return of the render function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to get the same result I got, just by using react
I can't seem to find a way to reach the unorderd list if I creat it in the return of the render function, I'm new to react and just found out that getElementById just returns null in this case

(create an unordered list, Clicking on one of the items toggle the color of the item's text color)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';


var defaultColor = 'black'
var specialColor = 'red'
var itemList =[1,2,3,4,5]
var id = document.getElementById('list')

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  name: 'React'
}
function toggleColor(ctrl)
{       
    if(ctrl.color == specialColor){
      ctrl.color = defaultColor
    }
    else{
    ctrl.color = specialColor;
  }
}
function createLiWithColorToggle(item){

  var newLi= document.createElement('li')
  var newFont= document.createElement('font')
  newFont.innerHTML = item
  newFont.onclick = ()=>toggleColor(newFont)

  newLi.appendChild(newFont)
  id.appendChild(newLi)
}
itemList.forEach((item)=>{
  createLiWithColorToggle(item)
})
    };

  render() {
return (
  <div>

  </div>
);
  }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<ul id = "list"></ul>
```

Comment: Where does the unordered list come from? Is it getting rendered by your react app?

Comment: You didn't `render()` anything, only an empty `<div>`

Comment: React is all about not accessing the DOM by yourself. You just manipulate the underlying data and react will render the changes according to your render function which doesn't do anything at the moment else then always rendering an empty `<div>`.

Comment: the thing is that if I change the render function to this:
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
                <ul id = "list"></ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
and remove the unordered list from the HTML, id.appendChild(newLi) won't work (Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null)

Comment: @AmitRomano You shouldn't be calling `appendChild`, `createElement` or any other method directly manipulating the DOM at all when working with react. You normally define the desired markup using `jsx` inside the `render()` method of your components and react will handle the creation and manipulation of DOM elements itself. It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Did you do the react tutorial?

Comment: As you probably figured, I just learned about react yesterday.. guess I have a lot to learn.. heading on to it.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with react you shouldn't try to create DOM elements yourself. Your components define the desired markup given the current state of your app. Rendering an unordered list could e.g. look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const defaultColor = "black";
const specialColor = "red";

// your initial data for the list
const initialItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: initialItems,
    selected: null
  };

  handleClick = item => this.setState({ selected: item });

  render() {
    const { items, selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li
            key={item}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}
            style={{
              cursor: "pointer",
              color: item === selected ? specialColor : defaultColor
            }}
          >
            {`Item ${item}`}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmmpj90lpj)

As you can see it is not necessary to create DOM elements yourself at all. React will handle all that for you. You just have to define the markup given the current state of the component.

Comment: @AmitRomano You are welcome. Please upvote and/or mark my answer as accepted when you think it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anythig (just an empty div) in the render method, you need to include something inside the `return()` block:

```
render() {
    return (
   <div>
     // Return something
   </div>
);
```

For more info, check [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: I know, as I stated if I try to return the  <ul id = "list"></ul> I can't find the id with getElementById and so I can't appendChild(newLi) in function createLiWithColorToggle